# JPA Eclispelink - unable to retrieve the last inserted record

Tags: caching, jpa, eclipselink, crud

I've a problem with JPA EclipseLink.
I've two functions: First, it inserts a row in the database correctly.
The second reads all the values ​​in the same table and show them to you. The problem is that it shows all the values ​​except the last quote, in order to make this appear, I must close and reopen the application.
I also tried to disable the cache does not work.
Do you have any idea on how to solve?
Thanks

Comment: How do you insert the record? Do you use JPA for the insertion? Otherwise JPA won't know about it. Post some code so that we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

How are you querying the quotes?  Are you accessing a OneToMany, or using a query?

If accessing a OneToMany, then it could be a caching issues, which you can disable to check,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F

A query should always get all objects from the database.  Ensure you committed the inserted objects.

The refresh a specific query see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching#How_to_refresh_the_cache